# grep: warning: recursive directory loop

Tags: unix, grep

I'm using Xshell to ssh an Unix server, and I'm trying to search for files containing specific text..

The command I'm using is: `grep -ilr "blah_blah_text" ./`

It found what I was looking for, but it also gave these warnings:

> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/ocean/dvorak/found:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/ocean/dvorak/testing/sea: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/ocean/dvorak/testing/found: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/ocean/testing/dvorak/found: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/ocean/testing/dvorak/monday: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/ocean/testing/found:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/testing/dvorak/ocean/sea: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/testing/dvorak/ocean/monday: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/testing/dvorak/monday:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/testing/ocean/dvorak/found: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/testing/ocean/dvorak/monday: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/dvorak/xhtml/mh370/testing/ocean/monday:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/ocean/dvorak/found:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/ocean/dvorak/testing/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/ocean/dvorak/testing/found: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/ocean/testing/dvorak/found: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/ocean/testing/dvorak/monday: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/ocean/testing/found:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/dvorak/ocean/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/dvorak/ocean/testing/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/dvorak/ocean/testing/found: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/dvorak/testing/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/dvorak/testing/ocean/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/gulf/xhtml/qwerty/dvorak/testing/ocean/monday: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/testing/dvorak/ocean/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/testing/dvorak/ocean/monday: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/testing/dvorak/monday:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/testing/ocean/dvorak/found: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/testing/ocean/dvorak/monday: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/testing/ocean/monday:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/dvorak/ocean/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/dvorak/ocean/testing/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/dvorak/ocean/testing/found: recursive
>   directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/dvorak/testing/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning: ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/dvorak/testing/ocean/sea:
>   recursive directory loop
>
> grep: warning:
>   ./svn/pages/india/xhtml/abcd/dvorak/testing/ocean/monday: recursive
>   directory loop

What do these messsages mean?

Answer (score 17):

You have to exclude symbolic links from your grep, they are reason of this warning. You should try to use find firstly:

> `find ./ -type f -exec grep -il "blah_blah_text" {} \;`

When you use find firstly you can omit -r in grep, because find is already recursive.

Comment: What would cause this if there are no symbolic links in the directory you are searching?

Comment: Can you provide warning message?

Comment: The same warning as discussed in this post, just Symbolic Links are not involved.

Comment: This does not print out the name of the file that contains the match, which sort of defeats the purpose of grepping a whole directory.